# Is DynamoDB guaranteed to converge to latest data when updates happen fast?

Tags: database, amazon-dynamodb, eventual-consistency

It is clear that Dynamo isn't thread safe when running updates/deletes in parallel (unless Optimistic Update Locking is used or Conditional Writes).

What I wonder though if there is a risk of having consistency issues when running updates one after another without any pause sequentially, something like this (Javascript):

```
await dynamo
  .put({ // PUT creates a record if it doesn't exist
    TableName: "table-name",
    Item: {
      id,
      value: "some value"
    }
  })
  .promise();
await dynamo
  .delete({
    TableName: "table-name",
    Key: {
      id
    }
  })
  .promise();

// wait for X seconds for eventual consistency here
const result = await dynamo
  .get({
    TableName: "table-name",
    Key: {
      id
    }
  })
  .promise();
if (result.Item) {
  throw new Error('Oh no, record should have been deleted!');
}
```

I've run this code a 1000 times and the results indicate that one can rely on Dynamo to behave as expected in this case (last update/delete wins), but I would like to be sure (a link to the docs?).

Update: in other words, I would like to know if Dynamo is guaranteed to respect the order in which I send the updates, when updates happen fast.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html

Comment: This is helpful, and it seems to indicate that my expectations are correct, quote: "If you repeat your read request after a short time, the response should return the latest data". However, it it doesn't specifically mention updates happening fast one after each other. I'm thinking - perhaps Dynamo needs to READ internally before doing a DELETE? And if it READs at a point when database hasn't become consistent yet, it might "think" there is nothing to DELETE?

Comment: Wikipedia definition for "eventual consistency" doesn't give me optimism either: "Eventual consistency is a consistency model used in distributed computing to achieve high availability that informally guarantees that, if no new updates are made to a given data item, eventually all accesses to that item will return the last updated value". Note the "no new updates" part of the definition

Answer (score 3):

Got a response from AWS support:

> In short, yes. No matter how quickly updates are happening, the latest update "wins". You will not have a situation where the DynamoDB service thinks the data is consistent but is not, leading to a long-term stale state. All "Write" type commands to DynamoDB (PutItem, UpdateItem, DeleteItem), which return an HTTP 200 success code, are processed in sequence.
> If I understand your example on StackOverflow correctly, you are putting an item and then immediately deleting it. That item will ALWAYS be deleted when run in that order. There will never be a situation where the PutItem happened too closely before a DeleteItem and then you end up with the item not deleted as you expected. Eventual vs. Strong consistency is only of concern when reading data [1].

---

> As you may know, there are two different ways to read an item from a DynamoDB tables, eventually consistent (default) and strongly consistent.
> [+] Eventually consistent reads are half-cost (e.g. 0.5 RCU for 4 KB item) but may return stale data if that item was updated within a few seconds before the read.
> [+] A Strongly consistent read are full-cost (e.g. 1 RCU for 4 KB item), may incur slightly higher network latency, and will result in the following outcomes:
>
> 1. HTTP 200 - Returns the item if it exists, or null if it does not exist. This is true no matter how recently the LAST Put/Update/Delete was run before the read.
> 2. HTTP 500 - An internal network error has occurred on our end, and you need to try the read again (This is rare)
>    What you will NOT see returned is stale data or an item that has been recently deleted.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a guarantee that you will be reading the latest *version* of the data, you should use strongly consistent reads. That way, when you query, you are guaranteed to read the *latest* value.

If you use eventual consistency, you *may not* read the latest value (~33% chance that read is stale). Empirically, the period of time in which reads are going to be stale is on the order of milliseconds, and the result of a stale read tends to zero as more time since last write passes, but there is no specific SLA for how long it could take for eventually consistent reads to reach consensus. Empirically, anything over a few seconds is going to be fine but again, if you need strong guarantees, you'll have to use strongly consistent reads.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. Perhaps my question wasn't clear. I've rephrased my question differently in the "update" section